# Sequence with conditional nodes in OWL

Tags: sequence, ontology, protege, linked-data

I want to represent a sequence of action in OWL using protege. What I want to be able to represent is statement like : "**if this action is true, then the next action is X. If it's false, then the next action is Y**". Also I can have several condition in the same sequence of action.

For the moment I can represent simple sequence of action but I can't manage to add those conditionnal nodes.

Example of what I'm doing now :

```
:seq1step1 :hasAction :SayHello ;
           :hasNextStep :seq1step2 .

:seq1step2 :hasAction :GiveYourName ;
           :hasNextStep :seq1step3 .

:seq1step3 :hasAction :SayGoodbye ;
```

I tried to add a property "hasNextStepIfTrue" but then I can't manage to make a Sparql query to get the full sequence because an individual can have the property hasNextStep or also hasNextStepIfTrue so I always end with only a part of the total sequence.

Maybe it is possible to query the full sequence in SPARQL but I can't find how.

[Here is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGog9.png) a screen of OntoGraf in protege to show what I want to represent.

Thank you !

Comment: What should "the full sequence" look like in the SPARQL results?

Comment: I want to have the first step and every node linked to the first node, then the 2nd node, then 3rd... The link can be done either with hasNextStep or HasNextStepIfTrue. But because I have more than 1 property hasNext, I can't make a Sparql query than give me every node. 
Either I'm doing bad with my Sparql query, or by creating a property hasNextStepIfTrue to represent a condition in the course of action.